# SQL - Adding a % sign to NVL output/result set - pictures and code included

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-null

I am having trouble adding a percent sign to the output of the `NVL()` function. If you look in the desired output picture you will see that the commission needs to have a **%** added to it. I've tried various things but have been unable to get it to output correctly. I have tried concatenating a percent sign but that messes up the `No Commission` text. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is  my code:

```
SELECT first_name,
       last_name,
       job_title,
       TO_CHAR(salary, '$99,999') AS salary,
       NVL(TO_CHAR(commission_pct*100), 'No Commission') AS commision
  FROM hr.employees e 
  JOIN hr.jobs j
    ON e.job_id = j.job_id
 ORDER BY salary DESC
```

[My Current Output]
[image]

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KSjA.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather use [`NVL2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/NVL2.html#GUID-414D6E81-9627-4163-8AC2-BD24E57742AE) function such as

```
NVL2(TO_CHAR(commission_pct*100), TO_CHAR(commission_pct*100)||'%','No Commission')
```

the second argument stands for `not null`, and the third argument for `null` cases.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for also explaining what the arguments mean. This really helped me out.

Comment: Nice to hear, Have a good week and studies @fice